# grid lines with for loop

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, jinja2

so I want to have three grid lines, such that `<div class="col-6 col-md-4">`
each grid line has a content of course. so the code will probably tell what I'm trying to achieve

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 col-md-4">

    {% for all_episode in episode %}
    <div class="card">
      <a href="{% url 'episode_detail' slug=all_episode.slug %}">
        <img class="card-img-top" src='{{all_episode.image.url}}'></a>

      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">
          <a href="{% url 'episode_detail' slug=all_episode.slug %}">{{ all_episode.title }}</a>
        </h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{ all_episode.story |slice:":100" }}...</p>
      </div>

      <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">
          <span class="h5">
            <a href="{% url 'series_detail' slug=all_episode.series.slug %}">{{ all_episode.series }}</a>
          </span> /
          <span class="h6">
            <a href="{% url 'season_detail' slug=all_episode.season.slug %}">{{ all_episode.season }}</a>
          </span>
        </small>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but with the above code i get the cards in align vertically. so one card takes the whole line while there  should be three cards.

Comment: Have you tried putting your column declaration inside your loop?

Comment: @Robert yes I've tried putting for loop outside row and outside col-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with your indentation please. It's difficult to read your code.
You can add your `col` class with your `card` div, and you need to have your loop into your `row` div but outside your `col` div.

```
<div class="row">
  {% for all_episode in episode %}
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 card">
      <a href="{% url 'episode_detail' slug=all_episode.slug %}">
        <img class="card-img-top" src='{{all_episode.image.url}}'>
      </a>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">
          <a href="{% url 'episode_detail' slug=all_episode.slug %}">{{ all_episode.title }}</a>
        </h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{ all_episode.story |slice:":100" }}...</p>
      </div>

      <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">
          <span class="h5">
            <a href="{% url 'series_detail' slug=all_episode.series.slug %}">{{ all_episode.series }}</a>
          </span> / 
          <span class="h6">
            <a href="{% url 'season_detail' slug=all_episode.season.slug %}">{{ all_episode.season }}
            </a>
          </span>
        </small>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: omgg thank you very much, I was about to give up. just one little thing, I want to set some martgin between each cards. can you please help me with that one??

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer. About your margin, you can update your CSS on your class **card**

Comment: yes that's the first thing i did but when I did that, when it's md it shows one card per row.

Comment: You can use a padding instead a margin. That will clear an area inside your card and not outside.

Comment: sorry for this basic question, but is it okay to use padding:10px? is it better to use other than px? i want it to be responsibe

Comment: It's ok. The responsive will be handle by boostrap grid. I invite you to read some documentation about responsive CSS :)